# Create big size byte array in order to get Ran out of memory retrieving query results

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I want to make a byte array with a really big value, so that it's size would be huge. I need that in order to replicate an `Ran out of memory retrieving query results.` error, while executing postgresql query.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

So what I basically need is to make `byte[] content = new byte[255];` size a big number so that it would crash while deleting it. Any ideas how I could make that possible?

Comment: `byte[] content = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hm, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`. But somehow it is not the desired result, it doesn't even start executing the query.

Comment: I thought you do want to provoke an out of memory error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want a `Ran out of memory retrieving query results` so as I understand I want jvm to run out of memory while performing the deletion query. Because it crashed on the server while doing that. That's because I want to replicate this error in order to fix it before pushing it back to the server with this flaw. And the error that I got now is appearing even before executing any of the queries.

Comment: `select array(select generate_series(1,10e6))` maybe then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How should I use this query in a test?